# How to make a '\n' or '<br/>' work rather than display it using django and html template?

Tags: python, html, django, web

I'm facing a serious problem with html and django.
What I want to do:

1. Create a table
2. Fill the table with python string
3. The most important one that I want to make line break for the string

What I've tried:

1. Use '\n' in the string
2. Use '
   ' in the String
   But they don't work, they are both displayed on the browser, I don't how to fix it.
   Can anyone help, Thanks a lot.
   `

```
<table border='1'>
  {% for x in datas %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ x.0 }}</td>
      <td>{{ x.1 }}</td>
      <td>{{ x.3 }}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>

x.3 is a string and I tried both '\n' and <br/> in it
```

`
[image]
[image]

Comment: try https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#std-templatefilter-linebreaks or https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#safe

Answer (score 0):

Break the strings wherever you need spacing. Suppose you have something like
"Someone" inside `{{data.variable}}`. Split and in between use   for spacing or 
 for vertical spacing